# How to know when to use parenthesis

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am reading through [An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/), and I see the following:

This code works:

```
(message "The name of this buffer is: %s." (buffer-name))
```

while this one fails:

```
(message "The name of this buffer is: %s." buffer-name)
```

However, this code works:

```
(message "The value of fill-column is %d." fill-column)
```

while this one fails:

```
(message "The value of fill-column is %d." (fill-column))
```

My question is why? What is the difference between `buffer-name` and `fill-column`? How do I know when to use parentheses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put - `buffer-name` is a function (that returns a string) and `fill-column` is a variable (that evaluates to an integer).

Functions calls in all Lisp dialects should be surrounded by parentheses.

To see details about a function in Emacs press <kbd>C-h f function-name RET</kbd>.
To see details about a variable in Emacs press <kbd>C-h v variable-name RET</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense. Is there a way to interactively know if a given symbol is a function, a variable or something else? (i.e. using `C-x C-e` or  any equivalent command)

Comment: I'd suggest the use of `M-x ielm` to experiment with Emacs Lisp in an interactive shell.

Comment: user273158: Take note that elisp symbols have both a value slot and a function slot, which means that a given symbol can (potentially) be used both as a variable and as a function. Interactively, `C-h v` shows you the help for a variable and `C-h f` the help for a function. Non-interactively, the functions `boundp` and `fboundp` tell you whether the value and function slots respectively for a given symbol are populated.

Comment: (some-name<pointer>), C-x C-e will evaluate variable value some-name; (some-name)<pointer>, C-x C-e will evaluate function some-name;
(symbol-function 'some-name) will return the function value.